# How to populate map of string and another map in a thread safe way?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety, guava

I am working on measuing my application metrics using below class in which I `increment` and `decrement` metrics.

```
public class AppMetrics {
  private final AtomicLongMap<String> metricCounter = AtomicLongMap.create();

  private static class Holder {
    private static final AppMetrics INSTANCE = new AppMetrics();
  }

  public static AppMetrics getInstance() {
    return Holder.INSTANCE;
  }

  private AppMetrics() {}     

  public void increment(String name) {
    metricCounter.getAndIncrement(name);
  }

  public AtomicLongMap<String> getMetricCounter() {
    return metricCounter;
  }
}
```

I am calling `increment` method of `AppMetrics` class from multithreaded code to increment the metrics by passing the metric name.

**Problem Statement:**

Now I want to have `metricCounter` for each `clientId` which is a String. That means we can also get same `clientId` multiple times and sometimes it will be a new `clientId`, so somehow then I need to extract the `metricCounter` map for that `clientId` and increment metrics on that particular map (which is what I am not sure how to do that).

What is the right way to do that keeping in mind it has to be thread safe and have to perform atomic operations. I was thinking to make a map like that instead:

```
  private final Map<String, AtomicLongMap<String>> clientIdMetricCounterHolder = Maps.newConcurrentMap();
```

Is this the right way? If yes then how can I populate this map by passing `clientId` as it's key and it's value will be the counter map for each metric.

I am on Java 7.

Comment: Use computeIfAbsent(): http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-

Comment: oops I am on Java 7. Sorry forgot to mention.

Comment: Using a concurrent map is a good start, but making sure updates are atomic is trickier, especially if you're not on Java 8.

Comment: Switch to Java 8 :-) Seriously, you should. As soon as possible.

Comment: It's not possible at all as of now. If it was my personal project, then yes I could have done that but I am part of company where we haven't started using Java 8 yet and it may take some time.

Comment: If contention is not a major issue, you may want to consider conventional locking instead of concurrent collections.

Comment: You can also use putIfAbsent(clientId, metrics), where metrics would wrap an AtomicLongMap, lazily initialized in a synchronized block. So creating a new Metrics each time would be very cheap, and contention would be limited to a single client ID.

Comment: let's say for clientId `abc` there were two metrics - `metricA` and `metricB` in the `metricsMap` and both of them count was 5 so next time when we get `metricA` for clientId `abc`, then `metricA` count should be 6 for that clientId instead of making a new `metricsMap` everytime for each clientId. This is what my intention is.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a map then you'll need to synchronize on the creation of new `AtomicLongMap` instances. I would recommend using a `LoadingCache` instead. You might not end up using any of the actual "caching" features but the "loading" feature is extremely helpful as it will synchronizing creation of `AtomicLongMap` instances for you. e.g.:

```
LoadingCache<String, AtomicLongMap<String>> clientIdMetricCounterCache =
        CacheBuilder.newBuilder().build(new CacheLoader<String, AtomicLongMap<String>>() {
            @Override
            public AtomicLongMap<String> load(String key) throws Exception {
                return AtomicLongMap.create();
            }
        });
```

Now you can safely start update metric counts for any client without worrying about whether the client is new or not. e.g.

```
clientIdMetricCounterCache.get(clientId).incrementAndGet(metricName);
```

Comment: I see. This is very nice.. I have updated the question with the sample code basis on your suggestion. That is what you meant right?

Comment: Yes although I wouldn't expose the private cache. You don't want clients of `AppMetrics` instances to modify it, etc. You might return the cache contents as an unmodifiable map view instead. e.g. `Collections.unmodifiableMap(clientIdMetricCounterCache.asMap())`. This will prevent client calls from creating additional `AtomicLongMap` instances too if no metrics are available for a given client. It will also not expose `LoadingCache` in your `AppMetrics` API in case you ever decide to move away from it you'll simply need to continue to adhere to the `Map` interface.

Comment: Sorry I was away for a while.. That's a good point. Let me explain you what I am trying to do so that you can give me some ideas or thoughts whether I am doing right or not. I am trying to create a metrics class (AppMetrics) which will hold all my metrics for a period of 30 seconds and then I want to reset those metrics. So every 30 seconds all my metrics will get reset.

Comment: This is how I am doing this. I am populationg all my metrics in `AppMetrics` class from different places in the code in a  multithreaded way. And then I have a different class which runs every 30 seconds from where I call `AppMetrics` class to get all the metrics, send those metrics to some other system by iterating them and reset them atomically.

Comment: I have updated the question with the code details from which it will tell you exactly what I am trying to do. Let me know if you have any thoughts or any ideas on that.

Answer (score 0):

A `Map<String, Map<String, T>>` is just a `Map<Pair<String, String>, T>` in disguise. Create a `MultiKey` class:

```
class MultiKey {
    public String clientId;
    public String name;

    // be sure to add hashCode and equals
}
```

Then just use an `AtomicLongMap<MultiKey>`.

Edited:

Provided the set of metrics is well defined, it wouldn't be too hard to use this data structure to view metrics for one client:

```
Set<String> possibleMetrics = // all the possible values for "name"

Map<String, Long> getMetricsForClient(String client) {
    return Maps.asMap(possibleMetrics, m -> metrics.get(new MultiKey(client, m));
}
```

The returned map will be a live unmodifiable view. It might be a bit more verbose if you're using an older Java version, but it's still possible.

Comment: What is `client` and `metricsType` here? I didn't quite follow?

Comment: Sorry. `clientId` and `name` in your example. I'll edit the post.

Comment: This is a good idea, but I think OP is collecting metrics by iterating though the key set. This way he'll have to iterate through the metrics of all the clients and filter out the ones for a particular client.

Comment: @shmosel Good point. The choice of data structure would depends which is done more often, incrementing the metrics or viewing them.

Comment: Yeah that's true, I want to iterate through keyset to collect all the metrics.

Comment: Viewing them will happen every 30 seconds but incrementing will happen more often so it looks like there is not much difference.

Comment: I think, I may have more than 20 clients but not more than 100 for sure.

Comment: I edited the post to include a suggestion for collecting metrics for a client.

Comment: Btw I am on java 7.